# is there an ExecuteScalar in Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

it looks like there was an ExecuteScalar in Dapper...

http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/issues/attachmentText?id=22&aid=220000000&name=ExecuteScalar.cs&token=9e2fd8899022f507b140ffb883c60e34

Was ExecuteScalar renamed or removed?

Can this now be achieved with .Query or .Query<T>?

Comment: The reason that we never added one is simply: `.Single()` does the same thing. We investigated the underlying implementations etc, and there is no real benefit in adding an extra method.

Comment: .Single() is not comming up as a Dapper extension method.  Is this in an underlying method in the .net framework?

Comment: I mean: `int value = conn.Query<int>(sql, args).Single();`, or `string value = conn.Query<string>(sql, args).Single();`, etc

Comment: note, that is an attachment you linked to ... this never existed in core

Comment: @Sam Saffron: I appreciate that. I was a looking at it from a C# interface angle first + was adapting old code.  Marc's answer about using LINQ's .Single() is far more elegant.  A simple touch like this makes the framework a lot simpler.  FYI: I just replaced some home grown commanding objects with Dapper.  We didn't have sql "command" caching and leaned on cached reflection properties for parameters + pushed these in via tokenised sql slabs via StringBuilder.  It worked okay, but Dapper is more concise and easier to use.  It feels more solid.  Thanks SO.

Comment: @Sam Saffron: ... also, didn't realise that this was never a part of the core.  Was getting aquanted with the open source project as I posted the question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ExecuteScalar was just added in 1.28: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper

Comment: I got a little confused by this, if I understand this correctly, in the current version of Dapper (1.42 as on 8th Oct 2015) there is NO execute scalar. The functionality is achieved via the LINQ method Single(). Right?

Comment: 1.42 still has it.  It uses the underlying SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar(), which has different behavior than .Single() and .First() (notably, it will return null if no records come back).  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 12):

I was able to call ExecuteScalar< T > with version 1.42.0

```
    public Boolean BeforeToday(DateTime dateInQuestion)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                String sql = @"SELECT CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN getdate() > @dateParameter THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BeforeToday";

                var result = conn.ExecuteScalar<Boolean>(sql, new { dateParameter = dateInQuestion });

                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return dateInQuestion < DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In version 1.50.4 I was able to call 
`connection.QuerySingle<int>(query,params)`

Comment: The same like `conn.ExecuteScalar<T>` ?